# `view.window` is nil inside `NSViewController-viewDidLoad`

Tags: macos, cocoa

I' trying to access `view.window` inside `NSViewController-viewDidLoad` but it's nil. Is there a way to force window to load inside `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the answer to your direct question is "no"; you can't make the window load from inside `-viewDidLoad`, you are simply in the middle of the nib-loading process at that point and it is what it is.  Depending on how your nib is constructed, and the internal details of AppKit, you might find that the window is sometimes loaded and connected up in `-viewDidLoad`, but it is not something you should rely upon, since it is not guaranteed.  You probably want to be using `-awakeFromNib` instead; it is called after all objects in the nib have been loaded and initialized, so the window should be set up at that point.

Comment: The problem is that, my view controller is not loaded from a nib, so `awakeFromNib` isn't get called.

Comment: OK, please add more context to the question, then.

Comment: What I want to know is the earliest point where I can access `view.window`

Comment: Without more context for what it is that your code is actually doing, I doubt you will get any help.  Post more code please.

Comment: `view.window` is still nil inside viewController>awakeFromNib (document-based application)

Answer (score 0):

You can get (or give a name to - which is rather more useful) the window in this situation in **viewDidLayout**   For instance.

up top in your ViewController class you have

```
@IBOutlet var bigView: NSView!
var toplevel: NSWindow?
```

then you add

```
override func viewDidLayout() {

    super.viewDidLayout()

    toplevel = bigView.window
}
```

you can then query toplevel.firstResponder at any other place in your code and get an answer. . .

Hope this Helps